# Cuda matrix multiplication: wrong output for large matrix

Tags: c++, cuda, visual-studio-2017, matrix-multiplication

I was trying to do a simple matrix multiplication using global memory on my GPU using Cuda 10. The code works fine for two 1024-by-1024 matrices, however, it produces zeros if the sizes increase to 2048-by-2048. I have tried to catch the cuda error, cudaGetErrorString() reports error at the following line:

```
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, M * N * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

It seems the indexing issue of the following lines in the kernel function:

```
for (int k = 0; k < S; ++k)
    val += a[row * S + k] * b[k * N + col];
```

Because if I comment this two lines out, the code works just as fine. I am wondering if the issue is caused by the limited capability of my graphics card or something else (i.e. the maximum grid dimension)? I couldn't find anything wrong with my code.

```
template <typename T>
void __global__ ker_matmul(T *a, T *b, T *c, int M, int S, int N) { 

    //dims_a[0] = M, dims_a[1] = S;
    //dims_b[0] = S, dims_c[1] = N;
    //dims_c[0] = M, dims_c[1] = N;

    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = tid / M;
    int col = tid % M;

    if (row < M && col < N) {
        T val = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < S; ++k)
             val += a[row * S + k] * b[k * N + col];
        c[tid] = val;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void cuArr<T>::cu_matmul(T *a, int *dims_a, T *b, int *dims_b, T *c) 
{
    if (dims_a[1] != dims_b[0]) return 0;
    fill_n(c, dims_a[0] * dims_b[1], 0);

    T *d_a = 0, *d_b = 0, *d_c = 0;
    int M = dims_a[0], S = dims_a[1], N = dims_b[1];

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, M * S * sizeof(T)); 
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b, S * N * sizeof(T)); 
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c, M * N * sizeof(T)); 
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, M * S * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, S * N * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 


    int threadsPerBlk = 1024;
    int numBlks = M * N / threadsPerBlk;

    ker_matmul << <numBlks, threadsPerBlk>> > (d_a, d_b,d_c, M, S, N);


    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, M * N * sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 
    cudaFree(d_c);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_a);

}
```

### GeForce GT 720, Kepler, 0.967 Ghz

SM                 |  2
SP (SP per SM)     |  384(192)
global mem         |  1 gb
const mem          |  64 kb
warp size          |  32
regs/blk           |  65536
max threads/blk    |  1024
max shared mem/blk |  48 kb
max block dims     |  1024 x 1024 x 64

### max grid dims      |  2^21 x 2^11 x 2^11

Comment: You may be hitting a windows WDDM TDR timeout.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, using a matrix side dimension of 2048

Comment: @RobertCrovella What kind of graphics card do you use? I have no idea of what happened to my machine. Both the GTX960M on my laptop and the GT720 on my desktop support only 1024-by-1024. I have tried to increase the WDDM TDR delay from 2 to 10 but didn't help.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Okay, problem solved! I ended up disabling the WDDM TDR. Now I can run larger matrices. However, it comes at a price -- the display gets frozen while the CUDA was doing the computation. Is there anything I could do about this without upgrading my graphics card?

Comment: Nothing can be done about it currently.  A GPU that is servicing a display will have the display servicing interrupted for the duration of any CUDA kernel execution.  These questions that you are asking are covered in many places on the web, including here on the `cuda` tag.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you for your answers, they helped a lot. I am quite new to CUDA, I have tried to search the answers for two days before I posted a question. I might just wasn't aware of where the root of the problem is. But thank you anyway!